# Responsive <img> for svg has overflow

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to have an `<img src="*.svg">` tag to display (any) svg file, however with what I have so far there is some overflow of the svg's viewbox when it fills the width:

[image: image of the overflow]

If I did not need absolute positioning, it works without any overlfow if you remove `display: inline-block` and use `max-width` and `max-height`, but since I need the image to fill its container, I have to use `inline-block`.

Thanks in advance for any help .

```css
    #inner-map {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    #map-svg {
        border-style: solid;
    }

    #map-svg img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80vh;
        display: block;
    }

    #pog-outer {
        position: absolute;
    }

    #pog-inner {
        position: absolute;
        left:-9px;
        top:-9px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="inner-map">
      <div id="pog-outer" style="top:58.794%;left:28.915%">
        <div id="pog-inner">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="18" height="18">
            <defs>
              <radialGradient id="Shiny" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.25">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD3333" />
                <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#990000" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000" />
              </radialGradient>
            </defs>
            <circle r="6" cx="9" cy="9" fill="url(#Shiny)" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map-svg">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/North_America_laea_location_map.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The code provided seems to work well in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I belive you can't control this since you can't change the wikimedia code. Instead of using an image with a variable aspect ratio `#map-svg img { width: 100%; height: 80vh;` use a square image

Comment: The overflow only appears when the image is filling the window's entire width @agrm

Comment: the "overflow" apears whenever the image either too wide or to high. You need to respect the aspect ratio

Comment: You've got a container with one aspect ratio and an image with a different aspect ratio. What do you want to happen? a) the image scales anisotropically i.e. ignores its aspect ratio and distorts to fit its container exactly b) what happens now i.e. you see the whole image but some edges have borders c) the image fills the whole container but some edges of the image overflow and are no longer visible

Comment: I want the image to keep its aspect ratio and be as big as possible while respecting `max-width: 100%; max-height: 80vh` @RobertLongson

Comment: Yeah c is want I mean, where the overflow is not displayed

Comment: @enxaneta an SVG fragment identifier can override the wikimedia code per my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per the question's comments you want the image to fill the whole container and then if the aspect ratio of the image and its container differ, some edges of the image would overflow and are no longer be visible.

So to get that we'd want the image to have have preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" on its root element but unfortunately it doesn't. It doesn't have that attribute at all and the default if you have a viewBox is preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"

We'll need to override that value by using an [SVG fragment identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers).

To make the example below more obvious I've also changed the width to width: 70vh; so it always overflows. You probably don't want to do that.

```css
    #inner-map {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    #map-svg {
        border-style: solid;
    }

    #map-svg img {
        width: 70vh;
        height: 80vh;
        display: block;
    }

    #pog-outer {
        position: absolute;
    }

    #pog-inner {
        position: absolute;
        left:-9px;
        top:-9px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="inner-map">
      <div id="pog-outer" style="top:58.794%;left:28.915%">
        <div id="pog-inner">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="18" height="18">
            <defs>
              <radialGradient id="Shiny" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.25">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD3333" />
                <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#990000" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000" />
              </radialGradient>
            </defs>
            <circle r="6" cx="9" cy="9" fill="url(#Shiny)" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map-svg">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/North_America_laea_location_map.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(xMidYMid slice))">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `height: 80vh;` with `height: 80%` in the  element and this way it's going to always hide the non-blue svg part and without making any overflow.

```css
    #inner-map {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    #map-svg {
        border-style: solid;
    }

    #map-svg img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        display: block;
    }

    #pog-outer {
        position: absolute;
    }

    #pog-inner {
        position: absolute;
        left:-9px;
        top:-9px;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="inner-map">
      <div id="pog-outer" style="top:58.794%;left:28.915%">
        <div id="pog-inner">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="18" height="18">
            <defs>
              <radialGradient id="Shiny" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.25">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" />
                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD3333" />
                <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#990000" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000" />
              </radialGradient>
            </defs>
            <circle r="6" cx="9" cy="9" fill="url(#Shiny)" />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="map-svg">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/North_America_laea_location_map.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This removes the vertical responsiveness and seems equivalent to removing `height: 80%`